# How to remove/eject non-existing External devices from Disk Utility?

Tags: macos, usb, disk-utility, external-disk, eject

For some reason *Disk Utility* (16.0) didn't eject my HDDs correctly and show the list of ghosts external drives as per below image:

[image: Disk Utility, Internal/External WD HDDs]

despite I've no any external hard drives connected. Ejecting them from contextual menu doesn't do anything.

---

I've tried to use `diskutil` to unmount these non-existing drives:

```
diskutil list
diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk2
```

but it didn't work.

Including this shell command to unmount them all:

```
$ while read disk _; do diskutil unmountDisk force $disk; done < <(diskutil list | grep external)
Unmount of all volumes on disk2 was successful
Unmount of all volumes on disk4 was successful
Unmount of all volumes on disk5 was successful
Unmount of all volumes on disk6 was successful
Unmount of all volumes on disk7 was successful
Unmount of all volumes on disk8 was successful
Unmount of all volumes on disk9 was successful
Unmount of all volumes on disk10 was successful
```

but the command doesn't take any (even with `force`) effect despite the successful message. So these disks are still showing after restarting Disk Utility as per below command:

```
$ diskutil list | grep external
/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
/dev/disk4 (external, physical):
/dev/disk5 (external, physical):
/dev/disk6 (external, physical):
/dev/disk7 (external, physical):
/dev/disk8 (external, physical):
/dev/disk9 (external, physical):
/dev/disk10 (external, physical):
```

---

The following log entries shows when unmounting a single disk:

```
$ log stream
opendirectoryd: Client: <private>, UID: 501, EUID: 501, GID: 20, EGID: 20
opendirectoryd: <private> completed, delivered 1 result
diskutil: (CoreFoundation) Loading Preferences From System CFPrefsD For Search List
diskutil: (CoreFoundation) Loading Preferences From User CFPrefsD For Search List
authd: (Security) SecTrustEvaluateIfNecessary
trustd: [com.apple.securityd.policy] cert[2]: AnchorTrusted =(leaf)[force]> <CFBoolean 0x7fffcc25d578 [0x7fffcc25cbd0]>{value = false}
authd: (Security) [com.apple.securityd.security_exception] CSSM Exception: -2147411889 CSSMERR_CL_UNKNOWN_TAG
authd: (Security) [com.apple.securityd.security_exception] CSSM Exception: -2147411889 CSSMERR_CL_UNKNOWN_TAG
authd: (Security) [com.apple.securityd.security_exception] CSSM Exception: -2147411889 CSSMERR_CL_UNKNOWN_TAG
authd: (Security) [com.apple.securityd.security_exception] CSSM Exception: -2147411889 CSSMERR_CL_UNKNOWN_TAG
authd: (Security) [com.apple.securityd.security_exception] CSSM Exception: -2147411889 CSSMERR_CL_UNKNOWN_TAG
authd: (Security) [com.apple.securityd.security_exception] CSSM Exception: -2147411889 CSSMERR_CL_UNKNOWN_TAG
opendirectoryd: Client: <private>, UID: 0, EUID: 0, GID: 0, EGID: 0
opendirectoryd: <private> completed, delivered 1 result
opendirectoryd: Client: <private>, UID: 0, EUID: 0, GID: 0, EGID: 0
opendirectoryd: <private> completed, delivered 1 result
opendirectoryd: Client: <private>, UID: 0, EUID: 0, GID: 0, EGID: 0
opendirectoryd: <private> completed, delivered 1 result
authd: Succeeded authorizing right 'system.volume.external.unmount' by client '/usr/sbin/diskutil' [30724] for authorization created by '/usr/sbin/diskutil' [30724] (13,0)
opendirectoryd: Client: <private>, UID: 0, EUID: 0, GID: 0, EGID: 0
opendirectoryd: <private> completed, delivered 1 result
opendirectoryd: Client: <private>, UID: 0, EUID: 0, GID: 0, EGID: 0
opendirectoryd: <private> completed, delivered 1 result
opendirectoryd: Client: <private>, UID: 0, EUID: 0, GID: 0, EGID: 0
opendirectoryd: <private> completed, delivered 1 result
authd: Succeeded authorizing right 'system.volume.external.unmount' by client '/usr/libexec/diskarbitrationd' [97] for authorization created by '/usr/sbin/diskutil' [30724] (2,0)
taskgated: (Security) [com.apple.securityd.security_exception] MacOS error: -67062
taskgated: (Security) [com.apple.securityd.security_exception] MacOS error: -67062
```

---

How do I get rid of these non-existing volumes without restarting the system?